# Sequelize MariadDb how to setup default value of priamary key to be uuid?

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

i was reading documentation for a while now but i couldn't figure this out. I need to set default value of primaryKey on all tables to be uuid. This is what i have now.

```
***cityModel***
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  return sequelize.define('Cities', {
    id: {
      type: type.UUID,
      defaultType: type.UUIDV4,
      defaultValue: type.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    code: {
      type: type.ENUM(...enumCode),
      allowNull: false
    },
    ***another fields***
};
```

As you can see in the picture i need set it up from sequelize to be uuid() as default, otherwise i will got error during insertion. (I got there No Default, i changed it manualy in HeidiSql)
[image: HeidiSql]

When i try to insert into db i got following error

[image: HeidiSql error]

Comment: I guess the defaultValue property is a function declaration(directly or indirectly), you can try to use `Sequelize.UUIDV4` as defaultValue.

Comment: Using `defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4` generates uuids on the sequelize client side.

Comment: XXLIVE i don't know what you mean, iam using that but it's doesn't helped

Comment: Matt thank you for clarification but i know that, i need help with setting it as default on db side, clients requires it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `sequelize.literal` or `sequelize.fn` in `defaultValue` option like this:

```
id: {
      type: type.UUID,
      defaultType: type.UUIDV4,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('UUID()'),
//      defaultValue: sequelize.fn('UUID'),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
```

Better way is to set a default value for PK in the DB (in a migration or an initial SQL script that creates a structure in a DB) and in this case you can setup PK in a model like this:

```
id: {
      type: type.UUID,
      defaultType: type.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true // this tells Sequelize that a value is generated by a DB and Sequilize does not indicate it itself at all
    },
```

Comment: THANK YOU! this is exactly what i needed many thanks!
But the autoIncrement options does not work for me, however, seuquelize.fn works flawlessly

Comment: Unfortunately i found that now it's creating UUID like this...
`{ "id": { "fn": "UUID", "args": [] } }